# Sup(f) = inf(1/f)

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ be a bounded, integrable function on $[a,b]$ with $|f(x)| \geq c > 0$.

Then does it hold true that for any subinterval of $[a,b]$ that $\sup f = \inf(1/f)$? It appears true in the case that $f$ is strictly positive or strictly negative. Looking for a counterexample when $f$ can be positive or negative, but have not come up with anything so far.

Answer (score 2):

It isn't true even if $f$ is strictly positive.  For instance, let $f(x)=1/2$ for $0\leq x\leq 1$.  $f$ certainly satisfies your conditions, but $\sup f=1/2$ while $\inf(1/f)=2$.

Answer (score 2):

Did you mean $1/\sup f = \inf (1/f)$?

Then you are right that for $f$ positive or $f$ negative, this is true.

Your counterexample can be the function $f$ defined on $[a,b]=[-1,1]$ by $f(x)=-2$ for $x\leq 0$ and $f(x)=2$ otherwise. 
Then $1/\sup f = 1/2$ but $\inf (1/f)= -1/2$.